# How to solve dependency conflicts between values within a FormFlow

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

I am using Microsoft Bot Framework with a FormFlow to let the user fill in a form.
Let's say my form has two fields:

- Country
- City

So I have two enums:

```
public enum Country {
    France, Germany
}

public enum City {
    Paris, Berlin
}
```

The field *City* always depends on the field *Country*, because a city belongs to a country.
That means the user should only be able to fill in either **France+Paris** or **Germany+Berlin**.

My form:

```
public class LocationForm
{
    [Prompt("Which country? {||}")]
    public Country? Country;

    [Prompt("Which city? {||}")]
    public City? City;
}
```

My builder:

```
private static IForm<LocationForm> BuildLocationForm()
{
    return new FormBuilder<LocationForm>()
        .Field(nameof(Country))
        .Field(new FieldReflector<LocationForm>(nameof(LocationForm.City))
                .SetDefine(async (state, field) =>
                {
                    switch (state.Country)
                    {
                        case Country.France:
                            field.RemoveValue(City.Berlin);
                            break;
                        case Country.Germany:
                            field.RemoveValue(City.Paris);
                            break;
                    }
                return true;
                })
        .Confirm(async (state) =>
                new PromptAttribute(
                    "You selected {Country} and {City}, is that correct? {||}"))
        .Build();
}
```

I don't know if the usage of *RemoveValue* is correct here, feels a bit hacked, but it works so far.

The first time the user fills out the form everything works fine, the user can only select either **Paris** or **Berlin** depending on the *Country* selected before.
However, when the user answers the confirmation question with **No** it is possible to change either *Country* or *City*. 
When the user then changes the *Country* from lets say **France** to **Germany** the FormFlow will ask:

> You selected Germany and Paris, is that correct?

Which is obviously **not correct**, but it is still possible to answer **Yes**.

I want to achieve, that, whenever the Country is being changed via the confirmation dialog, the user **has to change** the *City* selection depending on the change in the *Country* field aswell.

I was playing around with the *SetNext* method, but I couldn't figure out anything useful.

Am I on the wrong track here?
Is that even possible without hacking around the whole FormFlow implementation?

I would appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance!

Update (Additional Info): I tried the Sandwich Bot example given by Microsoft found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AnnotatedSandwichBot) and it seems to have the same (mis)behavior.
You get an extra (Free cookie/drink) when ordering a *Foot Long* sandwich. Changing the length to *Six Inch* after the confirmation you still have your extra, but only pay for *Six Inch*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is, inside the `country` field, validate if previous and new selections are same; in case its not clear the value of `city` so that city is prompted again.

Also change your city type to `string`, so that you can dynamically load the values based on selection of `country` instead of using `field.RemoveValue()` (Though that is not a bad approach)

So the code would be:

```
[Serializable]
public class LocationForm
{
    [Prompt("Which country? {||}")]
    public Country? country;

    [Prompt("Which city? {||}")]
    public string city;

    public static IForm<LocationForm> BuildLocationForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<LocationForm>()
            .Field(new FieldReflector<LocationForm>(nameof(country))
                .SetValidate(async (state, response) =>
                {
                    var result = new ValidateResult { IsValid = true, Value = response };
                    //Validation to check if the current country and previous selected country are same so that user is not prompted again for city
                    if (state.country.ToString() != response.ToString())
                        state.city = String.Empty;
                    return result;
                }))
            .Field(new FieldReflector<LocationForm>(nameof(city))
                //To get buttons SetType(null)
                .SetType(null)
                .SetDefine(async (state, field) =>
                {
                    //Any previous value before the confirm should be cleared in case selection is changed for country
                    field.RemoveValues();
                    switch (state.country)
                    {
                        case Country.France:
                            field
                                    .AddDescription(nameof(City.Berlin), nameof(City.Berlin))
                                    .AddTerms(nameof(City.Berlin), nameof(City.Berlin));
                                    //Add more description and terms if any
                            break;
                        case Country.Germany:
                            field
                                    .AddDescription(nameof(City.Paris), nameof(City.Paris))
                                    .AddTerms(nameof(City.Paris), nameof(City.Paris));
                                    //Add more description and terms if any
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }))
            .AddRemainingFields()
            .Confirm(async (state) =>
            {
                return new PromptAttribute($"You selected {state.country} and {state.city}, is that correct?" + "{||}");
            })
            .Build();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public enum Country
{
    France, Germany
}

[Serializable]
public enum City
{
    Paris, Berlin
}
```

Now you have the expected behavior. In case the country is changed, the city will be prompted again for selection. In case the user says `no` for confirmation and doesn't change the country and selects the previous selection of county itself then city is not prompted again, a direct confirmation of selected `Country` and `City` is prompted.

Emulator Response
[image]